# How do you think about the central estimate when the confidence interval is asymmetric?

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, bootstrap, econometrics, mgcv

I'm using a wild bootstrap to create confidence intervals around fitted values of the following model, for a specific combination of the factors, as x varies across its range.

```
mod = gam(log(lhs)~ s(re,bs="re",by=dum)
    +   as.factor(fac1)
    +   as.factor(fac2)
    +   as.factor(fac3)
    +   s(x,by=as.factor(fac1))
    +   s(x,by=as.factor(fac2))
    ,method="REML"
    ,data = dat)
```

I am not simply doing `predict.gam(mod, newdata=whatever,se.fit=TRUE)` because the dependent variable is a log, and the SE*1.96 overlaps zero.  What I want is a distribution of $lhs^{-1}|x$ that I can use in a monte carlo simulation, where I'd specify x and take a draw from the conditional distributon of $lhs$.

So I am using a wild bootstrap -- taking the residual vector, multiplying it by the Mammen distribution, adding it to the fitted values, and refitting the model to the resultant $lhs^*$.  To be precise, I am using a [cluster wild bootstrap](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAB&url=http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/research/slidesrobustsurvey.pdf&ei=dmdWUeiEN-3RiAKN14HYCg&usg=AFQjCNGF9WfkwauMaW4tNJpGhZzb0vAWmw&sig2=PLlkVNFsxs5NnAaIdg_zqQ&bvm=bv.44442042,d.cGE), because my data is clustered.  When I do so, I get this:

[image]

This is 50-odd bootstraped fitted values.  I want to sample from this when doing the monte carlo -- giving an $x$ and getting a possible value of $lhs|x$.  **My question:  since the central estimate is clearly not at the center of the distribution of fitted values, what, if any, information or value does the central estimate contain?  Or, should I take this asymmetry as an indication that I am either using the wrong tool, or using it improperly?**  If the latter, I'd greatly appreciate an explanation of why what I'm doing is wrong.

(Note:  this is a plot of $lhs^{-1}|x$.  I have also looked at plots of $log(lhs)|x$, which is what the model specifies.  It is are similarly non-symmetric, so my problem doesn't appear to be that the CI is simply symmetrical under transformation.)

(One more note:  the distribution shown -- above the central estimate on the left and below it on the right - is highly consistent with my priors).

Advice very much appreciated.